# npm run start does not work with my react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg

I've just started to work on a project.
I cloned the repo I installed the dependencies by running `npm i` but I keep getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\antfo\Documents\dev\TheCircle\thecircle-dapp> npm run start

> @my-app/monorepo@1.0.0 start
> npm run react-app:start


> @my-app/monorepo@1.0.0 react-app:start
> yarn workspace @my-app/react-app start

yarn workspace v1.3.2
(node:18940) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
error An unexpected error occurred: "patterns.map is not a function".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\antfo\\Documents\\dev\\TheCircle\\thecircle-dapp\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Users\antfo\Documents\dev\TheCircle\thecircle-dapp> node --trace-deprecation ...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\antfo\Documents\dev\TheCircle\thecircle-dapp\...'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I tried different Node versions but it does not work.
It's the first time that I work on a cloned repo so I might have missed something.

Comment: make sure to update yarn and also double check if you installed your dependencies with `npm install` or `yarn install`

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to using both yarn and npm in the same project, try deleting the 'node_modules' and 'yarn.lock' folders, then run 'npm install' or 'yarn install' and stick with one of them since it's not recommended to use both yarn and npm. and try again

Answer (score 0):

THis is because you havent install dependencies in repo.

just install dependencies it will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).